# What is the most efficient way to record siblings in a relational database?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a SQL database of individuals, identified by a unique key. I will need to record whether they have siblings, what gender they are, whether they are older or younger than the index individual and whether they are affected by a particular disorder. For these purposes, it does not matter whether their siblings are in the database or not, but the solution should work for the majority of individuals whose siblings aren't. My question: **what is the most efficient way to store this kind of information**? Do I create another table, or keep it in the same database as a serialised array, or some other trivial way I fear I am overlooking?

Comment: That would be good if all I wanted to know if whether they have siblings or how many they have. As you can see, the data about the siblings is pretty structured.

Comment: It all depends, of course, on how you will be working with that data.

Comment: Will you need to query data based on siblings?  If yes, the only logical solution is to create a separate table.  If no, then you should be fine storing the data as strings.  I personally would use a separate table regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `efficient` first.

Keeping siblings info as a serialized array (in a separate field) will work only if you are not going to perform any SQL operations over this field. For example, you are not going to find the person who has the biggest number of siblings.

Another table is needed if your application really has a `'Sibling'` entity. If siblings info is just an attribute of an individual (like a first name, just more complex in structure), you are ok to keep it serialized in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would tend to say: Never put a serialized array into the database. There is always a better solution.

How this solution looks heavily depends on the exact data you want to store and how you are going to access the data. Maybe you should add another table for each type of data, maybe you should add some kind of has-and-belongs-to-many table.

Sorry that there is no general answer to your question, but there is no omnipotent solution.